# Map escape key to "right alt" key on a mac keyboard in .vimrc

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I wanted to know how I could map the escape key to the right "alt" key on the mac keyboard ? Is that possible ?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm pretty sure that Vim can't tell between left and right alt, and even if it could I don't think you can map things just to alt. You need it to be alt + another key.

Comment: I second @Tumbler41: vim can't make a difference between right and left alt keys and I think I've seen other question about mapping something to alt only and if I remember well the answer were to make the terminal do that.

Comment: It's not vim-specific but you can have a look at https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en, it's useful for remapping specific keys. e.g. remapping caps lock with `<esc>` or `<ctrl>`

Comment: Yep thats what I am using and it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

For the Mac (pre Sierra) you can install [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) which lets you do that and more.

Look for Option_R to Escape.

If you already have Sierra you need to wait for the Karabiner update.

Comment: [Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) can do this.